# Create wpa_supplicant.conf from a Mac's preferred network list

Tags: macos, wpa-supplicant

Can I generate or export a wpa_supplicant.conf file from the preferred network list on my Mac?

Comment: What sort of use are you putting this file towards? A Little more information on how this is being used might be useful

Comment: @SimonSheehan It'd be used on a Raspberry Pi.